# Windows PowerShell default open location

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been googling and trying different options but I didn't really find anything useful or that worked.

My question is how to set default open location for windows PowerShell, I want it to always open c:/programming/ folder when I start it from like start menu, instead what it opens now.

I'm using windows 10.

Thnx for help

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help about_Profiles`. [*grin*] the usual method for what you want is to add a `Set-Location` call to your preferred profile.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'd put that as an answer

Comment: @JeremyThompson - thank you ... and it is done! [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks, yes it helped, I managed to create profile and set location there and now it opens by default, great !

Comment: @Filip - you are most emphatically welcome! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the usual way to tell PoSh where to start up at is to add a `Set-Location` line to one of your powershell profile files. i added ...

```
Set-Location D:\Data\Scripts
```

... to my `CurrentUserCurrentHost` file. you can learn more about profiles with ...

```
Get-Help about_Profiles
```

you can find your version of the profile i used thus ...

```
$profile |
    Select-Object -Property *
```

please note that *none* of these files exist by default. you will likely need to make one. if you do *be sure it is a plain text file, not a `.doc` file!* [*grin*]

Comment: yes thank you for help, i created my windowspowershell folder in the documents folder and created the powershell profile file and set location there and works like charm, thank you for help